# jdk install on centos

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, jdk

On Ubuntu I can do:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

What is the equivalent of that on CentOS?

If I do

```
yum install default-jdk
```

tt says

```
No package default-jdk available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 5):

`yum install java`

This will install the latest java openjdk available in CentOS (1.8.0_151 as of this post). Here are other examples.

`yum whatprovides *bin/java` will show you every package that provides the java binary, including the 1.6.0 and 1.7.0 openjdk's.

`yum search java` will show you everything that is related to java, whether or not that it provides the java binary or not.